# How to match the same Japanese letters on a CSV file and a string on the script?

Tags: python, csv, cjk

How to match the same Japanese letters on a CSV file: *data1.csv* and a string on the script. The `result` is going to be `None`. Maybe this is a word code issue but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/python
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 

import re
print "\n  <<<<< test start >>>>>"
print "############ csv data 1 ##############"

open_data1 = open("data1.csv",'r')
read_data1 = open_data1.read()
print "read_data1:",read_data1
print "############ txt data 2 ##############"

read_data2 = u"あ"
print "read_data2:",read_data2
print "############ result ##############"

result = re.search(read_data2,read_data1)
print "\nresult:",result
searched = result.group()
print "searched:",searched
print "  <<<<< test end >>>>>\n"
```

data.csv:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when you set the encoding to `utf8`?

Comment: Windows' (and Excel's) default Japanese file encoding is Windows-31J. Are you sure that the csv file is saved as UTF-8? If the csv files is in UTF-8, opening it on Excel would be failed (you will see other garbled character).